# tablesorter doesn't show up and down arrows

Tags: jquery, html, css, tablesorter

I am trying to use the JQuery tablesoter plugin but when it comes to show the arrows it doesn't show either down or up arrow when I sort descending or ascending order. It always shows up and down arrow (unsorted arrow). It seems table.tablesorter .header {...} overrides the table.tablesorter .headerSortUp {...} and table.tablesorter .headerSortDown{...} styles. Below is my code :

CSS

```
table.tablesorter .headerSortUp {
    background-image: url('../images/icons/asc.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center right;
}
table.tablesorter .headerSortDown {
    background-image: url('../images/icons/desc.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center right;
}
table.tablesorter .header {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-image: url('../images/icons/bg.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center right;
}
```

My table is in a velocity template but I don't think that will affect for this problem.

```
<table id="harvestTable" class="tablesorter" border="1">
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Source</th>
        <th>Time</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      #foreach($item in $self.harvestlist)
        #set($harvestId = $item.getFirst('harvestId'))
...
```

And I have included the relevant icons at respective folders. I am using the chrome and tested this on firefox as well but doesn't work in both. When I inspect the element in chrome, I can see that .header's image has overriden the .headerSortUp and .headerSortDown images. If i unselect .header's image, .headerSortUp image is correctly shown.

Have I missed something here? I really appreciate the valuable responses.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem you are having is due to [css specificity](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/) (try out [this calculator](http://specificity.keegan.st/)):

The default blue theme uses:

```
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortUp {} // (0,0,2,3)
```

so, in order to override this, you'll need a higher css specificity. One way would be to add a `th` to the sort class:

```
table.tablesorter thead tr th.headerSortUp {} // (0,0,2,4)
```

Comment: I didn't know about css specificity and this solved my problem as well as learnt something important too. Many thanks for your response!

Comment: FYI, for anyone finding this now, the tablesrter class names have changed, so for example `table.tablesorter thead tr th.tablesorter-headerAsc` and `table.tablesorter thead tr th.tablesorter-headerDesc`

Comment: Actually, my [fork of tablesorter](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) uses [`tablesorter-headerAsc`](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#cssasc) and [`tablesorter-headerDesc`](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/#cssdesc). The original tablesorter uses `headerSortUp` and `headerSortDown`.

Answer (score 2):

This is due to css preference rule. Last matched rule is always applied. to overcome this situation you can always use !important modifier, like in your case

```
table.tablesorter .headerSortDown {
 background-image: url('../images/icons/desc.gif') !important;
```

or

you just put .header css before .headerSortDown and .headerSortUp and it will start working.